# App crashes while opening UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am opening a **.xib file** which contains one `UITableView` in my `UIPopViewController` and I have given datasource and delegate methods of `UIATableView`.

But after calling cellForRowAtIndexPath method my app get crashed.

**My code is as follows:**

```
- (IBAction)btnOilChangePressed:(id)sender {
    OilChangeView *oilVC = [[OilChangeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"OilChangeView" bundle:nil];
   
       UIPopoverController *popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:oilVC];
        
        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 250)];
        [popView presentPopoverFromRect:btnOilChange.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    
}
```

following is the code on OilChangeView.m file

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayInfo count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"text:%@",[arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    
    // Configure the cell...
    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Lets start by asking for the crash log, this will give us some more to go one.

Comment: Have u added the delegates ??

Comment: @iPhone - Do you mind posting your answer. We have no idea what was broken and what got fixed. This question will remain a mystery here.